# How do I put specific words into their own div class using jQuery? (making a Chrome extension)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome-extension

I am making a chrome extension, and I want to find all occurrences of a certain word, and put them inside a new div class so I can change them with CSS.

Right now my content.js file looks like this:

```
(function() {

    function change() {
        var words = new Array("color");
        var html = document.body.innerHTML;
        for(var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
            var reg = new RegExp(words[i], 'ig');
            var html = html.replace(reg, '<div class="colorClass">'+words[i]+'</div>');
        }
        document.body.innerHTML = html;
    }

    change();

})();
```

But when I do that, entire web pages get messed up and become unrecognizable (for example, the "Color" wikipedia page).

When I try something simpler like:

```
var html = html.replace(reg, '<i>'+words[i]+'</i>');
```

It works just fine. Why is this whole page getting messed up when I try to add divs?

How can I fix this?

Comment: `console.log(html);` before you the document.body.innerHTML line and hit control+shift+i in the browser and select the console tab. What does that output look like?

Comment: @user4488861 do you mind accepting the answer if it worked for you?

Answer (score 2):

One reason the styles are messed up are because the native web page's CSS is overriding the styles loaded from your content script.

The second reason is that you need to be very careful when modifying HTML. You need be careful only to modify `text`. The current method you are using - you are possibly modifying html classes, ids, etc.

I've actually built an extension ([Source code](https://github.com/peterdotjs/Text-Search) for reference) that does something very similar. I'll share my learnings:

**JS**

I had used [`NodeIterator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeIterator) which is fairly unknown. I discovered this API a year ago from another extension: https://code.google.com/p/chrome-type-ahead/

NodeIterator will help you filter out the true `text` elements that you want to add styles to. This will help you avoid modifying any valid html(classes, ids, etc.) that matches your regex.

**CSS**

I would suggest adding a class to the `html` tag in addition to the html you are inserting. The reason for this is that you'll need to be very specific in your styles.

You want to avoid at all cost any chance of a collision with a selector of an existing page.

In addition you need to make sure to add your own css resets that are not only namespaced but also have `!important` on each attribute.

You CANNOT assume anything about the html tag that you are inserting. Sites can have very generic selectors that will completely mess up your styles. And also the sites can have very specific selectors (using `id`) that are more specific than you're styles (hence the need for `important`)

```
html.very-specific-class .very-specific-color-class {
  /*
    padding, margin, border, etc. 
    difficult to add all properties but add all the common ones at the very least 
  */
  padding: 0px !important;
  margin: 0px !important;
  border: 0px !important;
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because a `<div>` is a [`block-level element`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements), and it pushes other elements to a new line.
 `<i>` however, is an [`inline element`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elemente), so it will not change the page layout at all.

I would recommend using a `<span>`,instead of a `<div>`, as span's have no default styling in browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Because divs are block elements. You can use spans, which are inline elements:

```
var html = html.replace(reg, '<span class="colorClass">'+words[i]+'</span>');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want use `div`,you can add some css styles,like this:

```
.colorClass{display:inline-block;}
```